# Multi-value fields -- how to get totals?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, multiple-values

I apologize if the answer to this is obvious, I'm just completely new to SharePoint and need at least a pointer in the right direction.

I have a list with a "Choice" field. I've used InfoPath to modify the form input to use a multiple selection list box. The resulting list items look something like this:

```
    Title              Choices
     alice              foo, bar
     bob                baz, bar
     charlie            bip, baz, foo
```

What I want is a way to get the total instances of each choice within the entire list: e.g., how many "foo" in the entire list, how many "baz", etc. So far I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you building a custom webpart?

Comment: If you're open to 3rd party solution then PivotPoint will do this - http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/pivotpoint (usual disclaimer, its my own companies product)

Comment: @sssreddy No, not a custom webpart.

Comment: @Ryan, unfortunately my access is limited to using the current install as-is, but thank you for the tip! So am I correct in assuming there is not a simple solution for this that I'm just overlooking?

Comment: OOTB - Afraid not. If you were using single choice fields you could get most of the way there with a view grouped on the Choice field, but not with multi choice - you're going to have to develop something, either web part or client object model javascript (2010)

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of that. Looks like js is the way to go. Appreciate the help.